# Xcode - How reliable is the Assistant Editor Preview when viewing layouts for different screen sizes?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, nslayoutconstraint

The layouts being displayed in Assistant Editor Preview do not seem to be correct according to the constraints provided in storyboard. Also, I've noticed some weird behavior with the Assistant Editor Preview screen. If I have a 4 inch screen displayed in the Assistant Editor Preview with the layout properly displayed on it, if I add another screen size to the preview, it slightly changes the layout of the 4 inch screen which causes it to be incorrect. This change occurs without me even touching anything in Storyboard. All I do is add another screen size and suddenly everything is out of whack.

Can I correct this behavior? Should I not worry about what is displayed in Assistant Editor Preview so much?

Comment: I would run your application on different screen sizes using the simulator. If the layout is wacky there, then you know you have a constraint problem.

Comment: The editor preview is pretty useless, I wouldn't trust it for anything other than a very rough hint of what the view will really look like on a real device or in the simulator.

Comment: That's kind of what I'm starting to think also, rmp. Thanks for the reply.